# launching image_view for a topic

Tags: roslaunch, image-view, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to view the images my robot's cameras are receiving remotely.
The following in the command line will bring up a window with the video stream

```
$ rosrun image_view image_view image:=/stereo/right/image_raw
```

However I cannot find any information on how to put the "`image:=/stereo/right/image_raw`" part into a launch file

Alternatively, how can I use image_view in a python node to embed the video in a gui of my design?

I'm using:
ROS electric

Ubuntu 11.10

uvc_camera

Tkinter

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41756/launching-image_view-for-a-topic/) by [DocSmiley](https://answers.ros.org/users/2536/docsmiley/) on ROS Answers with karma: 127 on 2012-08-17

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is called remapping, and can be done using the [remap](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML/remap) tag.

You can display images from Python is using OpenCV's [imshow](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=imshow#cv2.imshow) function.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

here is what I did to get image_view to work from a launch file;

```
<node name="image_view" pkg="image_view" type="image_view" respawn="false" output="screen">
<remap from="image" to="/usb_cam/image_raw" />
</node>
```

---

Originally posted by [Dr Roboto](https://answers.ros.org/users/28339/dr-roboto/) with karma: 31 on 2016-12-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The question is quite outdated but maybe an alternative approach will help somebody:

```
  <node pkg="rqt_image_view" type="rqt_image_view" name="image_view_debug" args="/debug_img"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [msadowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/19897/msadowski/) with karma: 311 on 2019-03-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2